# Blob not Streaming Properly. NextJS + Vercel + PDFMake

Tags: next.js, vercel, pdfmake

I am generating a PDF on the server side then sending back to client. In localhost it works fine, once i deploy to Vercel (nextjs) I get an error.

Server Code:

```
      const fonts = {
        Roboto: {
          // Path relative to process.cwd()
          normal: 'src/pages/api/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf',
          italics: 'src/pages/api/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf',
          bold: 'src/pages/api/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf'
        }
      };

      const printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);
      const docDefinition: TDocumentDefinitions = await generateDocDefinition(patient);
      const pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);
      pdfDoc.pipe(BlobStream());
      pdfDoc.end();
      res.send(pdfDoc);
```

On Client:

```
const generatePDF = async (id: string) => {
  await apiClient
    .get(`/patient/generatePDF/${id}`, {
      responseType: 'blob'
    })
    .then((response) => {
      const file = new Blob([response.data], {
        type: 'application/pdf'
      });
      //Build a URL from the file
      const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      //Open the URL on new Window
      window.open(fileURL);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error: ' + error);
    });
};
```

In deploy environment it is hitting the catch block.

Comment: What error are you hitting? I know that Vercel limits the response body to 4.5mb, so if the generated PDF is too big that might be the issue. This error does not show up in development.

Comment: @Sliffcak, Did you resolve this in the end?